# Equality of integrals and derivatives

Tags: integration, derivatives, partial-derivative

Probably it's a very basic question but I am confused..
Is it a true that:

$$ \int\limits_{0}^{\infty}  \int\limits_{0}^{\infty} \frac{\partial^2}{\partial x_1\partial x_2}f(x_1,x_2) dx_1 dx_2 = \int\limits_{0}^{\infty}  \frac{\partial}{\partial x_1}\int\limits_{0}^{\infty}  \frac{\partial}{\partial x_2} f(x_1,x_2) dx_2 dx_1 $$

?

Comment: It's true sometimes.

Comment: It's called [differentiation under the integral sign](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Differentiation_under_the_integral_sign)